# Setting URL/PATH correctly for AWS S3 by using Paperclip/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have two models: `Collection` and `Letter`. `Collection` has many `Letter`s and `Letter` obviously belongs_to `Collection`.

Below is my Letter.rb file:

```
class Letter < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :collection

    has_attached_file :pdf,
                    :url => "/pdf/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :path => "/pdf/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                    :s3_host_name => host_name,
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :bucket  => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
                    :s3_credentials => {
                                        :access_key_id =>#ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
                                        :secret_access_key =>ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
                                    }

    validates_attachment :pdf,
                     :content_type => {
                         :content_type =>
                             ["application/pdf", "text/plain", /\Aimage\/.*\Z/, "application/msword"]
                     }

end
```

I have a question about `url` and `path` attribute in `has_attached_file`.

Instead of setting letter model's id in path, I would like to set collection's id. Additionally, I also wanna put `title` which is Letter's attribute. Let's say `@collection`'s id is 1. `@collection` has @letter1 and @letter2. When I save the files to AWS S3, I want to save it under `/pdf/1(which is collection_id)/:title`. How can I write this in `url` and `path`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Paperclip, you can use interpolations for that.

Your `has_attached_file` method would look somewhat like this;

```
has_attached_file :image, :default_url => "/pdf/:collection_id/:title/:basename.:extension"
```

Create an interpolation file, called `paperclip.rb` or `interpolations.rb` in the `config/initializers` directory (rails picks up any script in that folder on startup), which contains code that looks somewhat like this;

```
Paperclip.interpolates :collection_id do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.collection_id
end
```

Add the `:title` interpolation in the same way; add it to your `has_attached_file` urls, and create a second interpolation for that.

You can read more about this at https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations

In your case, I would suggest to also include the :id of the Letter in the URL, as it might be possible the user uploads two documents with the same title which might conflict.

```
has_attached_file :image, :default_url => "/pdf/:collection_id/:id/:title"
```

Paperclip uses the interpolations `:basename`, `:extension` and `:style` by default to create a unique path for the file.

- `:basename` is the base file name of the uploaded file
- `:extension` is the extension of that uploaded file
- `:style` is the "style" or size of that uploaded file

You can specify multiple styles (like thumnails in various versions). The default style is "original", which will contain the original uploaded file.

Read more about styles here; https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation

Always try to keep the original file as it can be handy in the future; when your site/application layout changes and new thumbnail sizes are required. You can rebuild/regenerate your whole thumbnail library from the original version.

Read more about generating/regenerating thumbnails here; https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation#generatingregenerating-your-thumbnails

Comment: In `config/initializers` directory, Do I make a `paperclip.rb` or something? in where should I put the interpolation code? And can you explain little bit about what `:style/:basename.:extension"` is doing? I don't know why but it is kept making `Original` folder in AWS. Is this happening because of `:style/:basename.:extension"`?

Comment: Hi, yes, you can create a script called paperclip.rb. That sounds logically, but it can have any name you like (interpolations.rb would be a good name as well). I'll update the answer regarding the `:style`, `:basename` and `:extension` property.

Comment: Thank you for the perfect answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Using gem aws-sdk for a ror application for uploading images to s3
Uploading images to a fixed bucket with different folders for each object or application.
The s3 keeps a limitation on the number of buckets creattion whereas there is no
limitation for content inside a bucket.

This code will upload image for a user to s3 using aws-sdk gem. The bucket and the image uploaded are made public 
so that the images uploaded are directly accessible. The input it takes is the image complete path 
where it is present, folder in which it should be uploaded and user_id for whom it should 
be uploaded.

```
  def save_screenshot_to_s3(image_location, folder_name,user_id)
    service = AWS::S3.new(:access_key_id => ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                          :secret_access_key => SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    bucket_name = "app-images"
    if(service.buckets.include?(bucket_name))
      bucket = service.buckets[bucket_name]
    else
      bucket = service.buckets.create(bucket_name)
    end
    bucket.acl = :public_read
    key = folder_name.to_s + "/" + File.basename(image_location)
    s3_file = service.buckets[bucket_name].objects[key].write(:file => image_location)
    s3_file.acl = :public_read
    user = User.where(id: user_id).first
    user.image = s3_file.public_url.to_s
    user.save
  end
```

Use  **key = folder_name.to_s + "/" + File.basename(image_location)** to customize the path you want to have.